# Why doesn't Active Directory return me a PagedResultsResponseControl?

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, jndi

I am attempting to enumerate all the groups in our Active Directory from Java. There are quite a lot, so I get a `SizeLimitExceededException` after 1000 results. I am attempting to use `PagedResultsControl`, with my code very closely modelled on all the examples out on the web, and it sort-of-works, in that it no longer throws the `SizeLimitExceededException`, and returns a number of results matching the specified page size (provided that isn't greater than 1000).

However, the next step is to get the cookie from the response and use it to get the next page, and my issue is that **there is no PagedResultsResponseControl in the context** after the call to `search()`. In fact `getResponseControls()` returns `null`.

I have searched extensively and can't seem to find anyone else reporting this issue, and I'm pretty much stuck here. So what am I doing wrong? Why don't I get a `PagedResultsResponseControl`?

Our domain is running on Windows Server 2016 and I have reduced my code down to the following test case:

```
public class PagingTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<>();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "username");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://campus.uni.ac.uk/DC=campus,DC=uni,DC=ac,DC=uk");
        LdapContext adContext = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);

        // Set up search controls.
        SearchControls searchControl = new SearchControls();
        searchControl.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
        String[] attributesToFetch = {"cn"};
        searchControl.setReturningAttributes(attributesToFetch);

        // Set up a paged search.
        final int pageSize = 500;
        byte[] cookie = null;
        adContext.setRequestControls(new Control[]{
                new PagedResultsControl(pageSize, Control.CRITICAL)
                });

        // Do the search.
        int count = 0;
        boolean finished = false;
        while (!finished) {
            NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> records
                    = adContext.search("OU=Groups", "objectClass=group", searchControl);

            // Examine the page's results control response and act accordingly.
            Control[] controls = adContext.getResponseControls();
            if (controls != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < controls.length; ++i) {
                    if (controls[i] instanceof PagedResultsResponseControl) {
                        PagedResultsResponseControl prrc =
                                (PagedResultsResponseControl) controls[i];
                        cookie = prrc.getCookie();
                        if (cookie == null) {
                            finished = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                cookie = null;
                finished = true;
            }

            // Process the page of results.
            while (records != null && records.hasMore()) {
                SearchResult sr = records.next();
                Attributes attribs = sr.getAttributes();
                BasicAttribute ba = (BasicAttribute) attribs.get("cn");
                String cn = (String) ba.get();
                System.out.println(cn);
                ++count;
            }

            // Re-activate paged results with the new cookie.
            adContext.setRequestControls(new Control[]{
                    new PagedResultsControl(pageSize, cookie, Control.CRITICAL)
                    });
        }
        System.out.println("Found " + count + " groups");
    }
}
```

Comment: Try looking at: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/newstuff/paged-results.html

Comment: @jwilleke My code is very closely based on the code on this, and other Oracle tutorial pages. Was there a specific error that you think I have made in adapting it?

Comment: Maybe you're not getting any results at all and so it doesn't bother to return the control. Try printing your records first to see what you have.

Comment: @squarewav There are nearly 9,000 groups returned by the query, and as I stated in the question the server is returning the appropriate number of results for the requested page size (500 in this case), and the test code is printing them out.

Comment: I have run into this same issue and have found an answer: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/ldap-paged-queries-subordinate-referrals-not-chased

The above doc matched the LDAP behaviour I was seeing in .NET, and was also throwing `error code 12 - 00000057` logs and causing issues in a java application. 
Switching to global catalog port `3269` fixed it for the java app, but I also tested disabling ReferralChasing & searching on a non-root OU (e.g. OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=com instead of just DC=domain,DC=com) in .NET which also worked.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your *ldap server does not support paging query*, you *can use ldapsearch* command like this:

```
ldapsearch -H ldap://xxxx:389 -x -D "uid=zhangsan,ou=employee,dc=test,dc=com" -W -b "" -s base -a always "(objectClass=*)" "supportedControl"
```

If the return values contain `1.2.840.113556.1.4.319`, it shows your *ldap server supports paging query*.

Comment: As I said, this is Active Directory, which does support paging. But I have run the above command (with a suitable real user) and confirmed that `1.2.840.113556.1.4.319` is definitely on the list of supported controls.